# создание задержки клавишам в pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pyautogui, key

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы сигналы с клавиатуры считывались не сразу, то есть чтобы действие назначенное на нажатие той или иной клавиши происходило не сразу, а к примеру через 3 секунды после нажатия
вот пример кода:

```
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            print('left key')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        pygame.time.delay(3000)
        print('left key')
```

Время в миллисекундах, т.е. 1000 = 1 секунде

Comment: а как сделать так, что бы оно отсрочивало только print а не всю программу в целом